# How to change the IP of the FEDERATE repository setup in WAS

Tags: ldap, websphere, single-sign-on

I have already configured the LDAP setup in federate repository and it was working fine. But now suddenly the IP of the LDAP server got changed, for which I am not able to login to WAS. Is there any file which contain the LDAP IP, so that I will directly change and may be it will login then.

Comment: Always use hostnames/aliases rather that ip names, it is much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Federated repository information is saved in the wimconfig.xml under

> [profile]/config/cells/[cell_name]/wim/config/wimconfig.xml

You can edit the LDAP host information here.